# Getting X and Y coordinates from tile ID

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, canvas

I'm stumped on what is probably some pretty simple math. I need to get the X and Y coordinates from each tiles referenced ID. The grid below shows the order the ids are generated in. Each tile has a width and height of 32. Number ones x & y would be equal to (0,0). This is for a game I'm starting to make with canvas using a tileset.

1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9

So far for X, I've come up with...

`(n % 3) * 32 - 32` // 3 is the width of the source image divded by 32

And for Y...

`(n / 3) * 32`

This is obviously wrong, but It's the closest I've come, and I don't think I'm too far off from the actual formula.

Here is my actual code so far:

```
function startGame() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("rpg");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const tileSet = new Image();
  tileSet.src = "dungeon_tiles.png";
  let map = {
    cols: 10,
    rows: 10,
    tsize: 32,
    getTileX: function(counter, tiles) {
      return ((tiles[counter] - 1) % 64) * 32;
    },
    getTileY: function(counter, tiles) {
      return ((tiles[counter] - 1) / 64) * 32;
    }
  };
  let counter = 0;
  tileSet.onload = function() {
    for (let c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
      for (let r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
        let x = map.getTileX(counter, mapObj.layers[0].data); // mapObj.layers[0].data is the array of values
        let y = map.getTileY(counter, mapObj.layers[0].data);
        counter += 1;
        ctx.drawImage(
          tileSet, // image
          x, // source x
          y, // source y
          map.tsize, // source width
          map.tsize, // source height
          r * map.tsize, // target x
          c * map.tsize, // target y
          map.tsize, // target width
          map.tsize // target height
        );
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The very first thing you need to do is `(n-1)` for both X and Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `1` is `(0,0)` and each tile is `32*32`, then finding your horizontal position is a simple `32*(t-1)` where `t` is your tile number. `t-1` because your tiles start from `1` instead of `0`. Now, you have `3` tiles per row so you want to reset every 3, so the final formula for your `x` is `32*((t-1)%3)`.

For the vertical position it's almost the same, but you want to increase your position by `32` only once every `3` tiles, so this is your `y`: `32*floor((t-1)/3)`.

`floor((t-1)/3)` is simply integer division since the numbers are always positive.

Comment: Awesome, that did it. Any advice on how to approach math problems like this? The math was so simple it really hurts my programming ego not being able to solve it.

Comment: @JacobMoore it's mostly experience. You'd be surprised to see how much the same math problems keep coming back when programming. Don't worry about being stuck, the important thing is that when you solve the problem you don't just copy-paste the solution, but you understand it. This way, you'll only be stuck once and never again, because now you know how to solve it. Other than that, try to write down the result you want. Try to look for some sort of pattern in those numbers. For example, if you see numbers going up and down and back up and back down, there's probably a modulo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to get the 1|2|3 values based on x, y correct? You can do something like this:

`((y * total # of rows) + x) + 1`

This would convert the 2D x, y index to a single index which is, as you stated, 1|2|3. This formula is based on your example where count starts at 1 and not 0. If you want to convert it to 0 base, just remove the + 1.

If you have the width and height, or probably location of input/character, you can have a GetX(int posX) and GetY(int posY) to get the x and y based on the position. Once you have converted the position to x, y values, use the formula above.

```
int GetX(int posX)
{
    return (posX / 32);
}

int GetY(int posY)
{
    return (posY / 32);
}

int GetIndex(int posX, int posY)
{
    return ((GetY(posY) / totalRows) + GetX(posX)) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's the other way around. I have an array of values [1,5,6,3,5,5] where from each one of those values I need the X and Y of it.

Comment: Right.. So you need to get one of the two before you can get the other. What I can think of is get the X first by doing something like:

`x = (id - 1) % width`

Then once you get the X, we get the Y based on the formula from the answer above:

`y = (id - 1 - x) / rows`

For example, we have 5 columns and 4 rows
`1|2|3|4|5`
`6|7|8|9|10`
`11|12|13|14|15`
`16|17|18|19|20`

If id = 19, then
`x = (19 - 1) % 5 = 3`

Then now we have X, get the Y
`y = (19 - 1 - 3)/4 = 3`

So from id = 19, we got x = 3, y = 3